# using Jquery to reference two different forms

Tags: jquery

I am still new to Jquery and need to reference two forms, the problem is both of my forms have the same IDs. I want to get the name from form1 and populate it into form2, I would problably use this in javascript.

```
      document.form2.name.value = document.form1.name.value
```

but i want to di the same in Jquery something like below. Can anyone help me please and I hope it makes sense to you all , thanks

```
      ref  = $('#name' FORM1).val() ;

      $('#name' FORM").val( ref ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid for two elements to have the same ID.  Elements have to have a unique ID in the DOM.  What you probably want to do is give them the same name, but different IDs.  Then you would do something like:

```
var formdata = []
$("#form1 input").each(function (index, item) {
   formdata.push($(item).val());
});
$("#form2 input").each(function (index, item) {
   $(item).val(formdata.shift());
});
```

This assumes that each input in the first form matches the input in the second form in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference an element by a specific name like this:

```
var element = $("[name=" + name + "]");
```

Where **name** is a variable holding the name of the element (a form for example)

In your case (without a variable):

```
var form1 = $("form[name=form1]");
var form2 = $("form[name=form2]");

// copy the value of input element with name "name" from form2 to form1
$("input[name=name]",form1).val($("input[name=name]",form2).val());
```